# "I haven't finished with that" vs "I wasn't finished with that"

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice

I've just seen that example of usage "I wasn't finished with that" http://9gag.com/gag/aep02N5

And it seems incorrect to me.

Why wouldn't I use "I haven't finished with that" instead?
Is it correct to use passive voice there?

Comment: Neither of the above is a passive construction. 'I was finished ...' is interpretable either as a rare be-perfect still in use, or as a participial adjective construction (he was preoccupied with ...). 'The housework was finished' is passive, as 'housework' is not the agent.

Comment: I haven't ever read about that style of using present perfect (I was + 3d form). Could you provide some links please?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Also, how can I distinguish that "specific present perfect usage" from the "passive voice"? f.e. "I wasn't asked about that", how can I figure out the meaning, if it could be about me being asked or about some one else being asked?

Comment: (1) See [Is it acceptable to use “is become” instead of “has become”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3402/is-it-acceptable-to-use-is-become-instead-of-has-become), and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217263/winter-is-gone-and-spring-is-come) (but note that 'He is finished' is also still used synonymously with 'He has finished') // (2) The be-infinitive is used with very few verbs nowadays. 'He is finished' is ambiguous; contextual cues usually disambiguate. Note also the ambiguity of 'the window was broken': participle adjective, or passive construction?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you. If you made an answer from your comment I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the variants is a passive construction.

'I was finished ...' is interpretable either as a rare be-perfect (strictly, a be-past-perfect) still in use, which some might label as 'archaic' or perhaps 'colloquial' – or as a participial adjective construction (compare 'he was preoccupied with ...'). See [Is it acceptable to use “is become” instead of “has become”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3402/is-it-acceptable-to-use-is-become-instead-of-has-become), and [Winter is gone and spring is come {duplicate}](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217263/winter-is-gone-and-spring-is-come) (but note that 'He is / He's finished / done [with the computer now]' are also still used synonymously with 'He has finished [...]', in more than one register. [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be-done-with) actually classes 'be done with' and 'have done with' as fixed (apart from verb inflections) idioms.) On the other hand, 'The housework was finished' is a passive construction (unless interpreted as a participial adjective following the copula), as 'housework' is not the agent.

The be-infinitive is used with very few verbs nowadays. 'He is finished' is ambiguous; contextual cues usually disambiguate. Note also the well-known ambiguity of 'the window was broken', where the be-perfect *cannot* apply: is this an example of a participle adjective, or a passive construction?

Answer (score 2):

To my British English-tuned ears, *I haven't finished* sounds like the correct usage. If you flip the sentences then *I have finished* makes sense while *I was finished* sounds like you were fatigued or dying. Or American.

Comment: So, using "wasn't" for present perfect in some cases - it's like American English style? It is really strange for me, I haven't ever read about this.

Comment: @BergP I've just found [the 'Which is correct: “I’m done” or “I have finished”?' thread](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150661/which-is-correct-i-m-done-or-i-have-finished). Have a look there, and at the linked article.

Answer (score 0):

IT is a slight difference in tense, with the understanding that the person thought you were finished with that some time ago. I started using this thing a week ago, and haven't used it in a couple of days, so a coworker grabbed it saying that they assumed I was finished with that. I wasn't finished with it, but I understand why the person assumed that I was.

As opposed to something that I just stopped using and the question relates to whether I am or am not now finished with it, to which the answer is that I'm just going to grab a coffee, and no I haven't finished with it yet.

Comment: So "I wasn't finished with that" the same with "I didn't finish with that" ?

Comment: No **!** "I wasn't finished with that **!** "  is the same as "I haven't finished with that **!** "   Use 'I didn't finish...'  with "..until..." (until yesterday, until the time was up, all in the done-and-dusted past.)